# Cannot delete docker image in docker hub. How can I delete a docker image succefully?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image, dockerhub

I log in the docker hub and want to delete some docker images from my repository. I enter the image page in the repository and go `setting`. I push the button `delete repository` at the bottom of the page and enter the repository name. Everything goes well now. I push the button delete, after a few seconds, it turns to the repository list page. It seems the repository I want to delete is no longer in the list. However, when I refresh the repository list page, the deleted image repository appears again and I can delete it once again but it still appears when I refresh the page.

How can I successfully delete one of my image repository in docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, but image get deleted after few minute. It just take few minutes to actually delete the image.